# ¿Como separar los datos que vienen de un TextArea en PHP?

Tags: php

Buenas tardes lo que quiero hacer es obtener todos los datos que se ingresan en un 
textarea  y en php poder separarlos por salto de lina y por coma

De esta forma:

Estoy usando codeigniter

```
$variablecontenedora = $this->input->post("contenedor");
```

las tres filas estan guardadas en la variable $variablecontenedora.

```
Familia 01 , Grupo 01 , Descripcion 01
Familia 02 , Grupo 02 , Descripcion 02
Familia 03 , Grupo 03 , Descripcion 03
```

y quiero sapararlo de esta forma

la primera fila :

```
$fila_1 = Familia 01 , Grupo 01 , Descripcion 01;
```

luego los datos de esa variable quiero separarlos por las comas

```
$coma_1:Familia 01;
$coma_2:Grupo 01;
$coma_3:Descripcion 01;
```

y asi sucesivamente con las otras filas que estan en el texarea

La cantidad de columnas son exactos solo estarán 3.

Las filas son indeterminadas

Comment: Para responder bien a este tipo de preguntas conviene que digas el uso posterior de esos datos. Porque como tienes planteada la pregunta parecería que requieres generar variables dinámicas según el número de filas que haya en los datos. ¿Necesitas guardar una variable por cada grupo de comas? ¿para qué serían esa variables?  ¿O simplemente deseas mostrar el contenido organizado de una cierta forma? Creo que es un elemento importante que deberías aclarar en tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo que estoy haciendo es que cuando copien  los datos de cualquier documento y lo pegen en un textarea esos datos se inserten en sus respectivas columnas de las tablas, **ya pude hacer que inserten gracias a la respuesta de Jose Melendez**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes aplicarle dos veces la función explode. En la primera función te genera un elemento por cada linea del textarea. Y luego aplicar nuevamente el explode a cada linea para separarlo por comas. El resultado lo almacenas en un array multidimensional $separado_por_comas, donde cada elemento del array es a su vez otro array con tres elementos, uno por cada columna.

```
$separado_por_salto = explode("\n", $variablecontenedora);

foreach($separado_por_salto as $lineas){
    $separado_por_comas[] = explode(",", $lineas);
};
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Buenas a la hora de usar explode me  arroga ese error  **explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given**

Comment: Podrías hacer un var_dump sobre la variable $variablecontenedora?

Comment: Si me mostro el contenido del texarea en array  use ( var_dump($variablecontenedora); ): **array(1) {[0]=> string(118) "Familia 01 , Grupo 01 , Descripcion 01 Familia 02 , Grupo 02 , Descripcion 02 Familia 03 , Grupo 03 , Descripcion 03"}**

Comment: Ok, pero mira que la información del textarea te esta llegando como un array, por eso te da error. Entonces al momento de asignar a $variablecontenedora la información de textarea tendría que ser $variablecontenedora = $idenficiadortextarea[0], para que solo te asigne el contenido del string. Lo que no sabría decirte es porque la información del textarea te llega como array.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `explode`, que separa `strings` usando el caracter que quieras. 
 Primero puedes separar por cambio de linea `\n` y luego por comas asi:

```
$filas = explode("\n", $variablecontenedora);
foreach($filas as $fila){
  $comas = explode("," $fila);
  //Si quieres tres variables
  $coma_1 = $comas[0];
  $coma_2 = $comas[1];
  $coma_3 = $comas[2];
}
```

Comment: saludos es bueno verte apoyando, sin embargo te recuerdo que en SO se esperan respuestas completas es decir código mas la explicación; sería genieal que comentaras por que este código soluciona el problema

Comment: Buenas a la hora de usar explode me  arroga ese error  **explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given**

Comment: Te da el error en el primer explode o en el segundo?